# Parse_detail not working in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

Hello i am new to Scrapy. And i am trying to use scrapy with scrapyd

I am trying to scrap this two website, and somehow one of the website is not working eventhough i use basically same spider.py file. Only changing some

Please kindly help

the scrapyd

```
#the Working spider
scrapyd.schedule("default", "detik", settings=settings, url=url, domain=domain)
#the NOT Working spider
scrapyd.schedule("default", "kompas", settings=settings, url=url, domain=domain)
```

the Working spider code

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule

class NewsSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'detik'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.url = kwargs.get('url')
        self.domain = kwargs.get('domain')
        self.start_urls = [self.url]
        self.allowed_domains = [self.domain]
        print("READY TO GO TO DETIK")

    def parse(self, response):
        print("INSIDE OF DETIK")
        urls = response.xpath("//article/div/a/@href").extract()        
        for url in urls:
            print(url)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_detail)    

    def parse_detail(self, response):
        print("SCRAP EVERY LINK DETIK")
        i = {}
        i['breadcrumbs'] = response.xpath("//div[@class='breadcrumb']/a/text()").extract()
        i['tanggal'] = response.xpath("//div[@class='date']/text()").extract_first()
        i['penulis'] = response.xpath("//div[@class='author']/text()").extract_first()
        i['judul'] = response.xpath("//h1/text()").extract_first()
        i['berita'] = response.xpath("normalize-space(//div[@class='detail_text'])").extract_first()
        i['tag'] = response.xpath("//div[@class='detail_tag']/a/text()").extract()
        i['url'] = response.request.url
        i['website'] = 'detik'
        return i #Goes to Pipeline
```

the NOT WORKING spider code

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule


class KompasSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'kompas'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.url = kwargs.get('url')
        self.domain = kwargs.get('domain')
        self.start_urls = [self.url]
        self.allowed_domains = [self.domain]
        print("READY TO GO TO KOMPAS")

    def parse(self, response):
        print("INSIDE OF KOMPAS")
        urls = response.xpath("//h3/a/@href").extract()        
        for url in urls:
            print(url)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_detail)

    def parse_detail(self, response):
        print("SCRAP EVERY LINK KOMPAS")
        i = {}
        i['breadcrumbs'] = response.xpath("//a/span/text()").extract()
        i['tanggal'] = response.xpath("substring(//div[@class='read__time']/text(),14,21)").extract_first()
        i['penulis'] = response.xpath("//div[@class='read__author']/a/text()").extract_first()
        i['judul'] = response.xpath("//h1[@class='read__title']/text()").extract_first()
        i['berita'] = response.xpath("normalize-space(//div[@class='read__content'])").extract_first()
        i['tag'] = response.xpath("//li/a[@class='tag__article__link']/text()").extract()
        i['url'] = response.request.url
        i['website'] = 'kompas'
        return i
```

i think the problem is they are not going through the parse_detail. cause the print("SCRAP EVERY LINK KOMPAS") is not being printed in the log.

Comment: can you print it `urls = response.xpath("//h3/a/@href").extract()` are there something ? in `KompasSpider`

Comment: Yes, they, the urls is catch well. some url. https://edukasi.kompas.com/read/2018/05/28/21142851/evaluasi-un-smp-unbk-meminimalkan-praktek-kecurangan

Comment: Okay, it's because the allowed domain is news.kompas.com i have changed it into the kompas.com and it's work. Thanks